# How to confirm Cognito User after it was created with adminCreateUser command

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

After creating a Cognito user with

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-east-1"
});
```

```
const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
  apiVersion: "2016-04-19",
  region: "us-east-1"
});

let USER_POOL_ID = "my-cognito-user-pool-id"

var poolData = {
  UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID,
  Username: "user-001@google.com",
  DesiredDeliveryMediums: ["EMAIL"],
  TemporaryPassword: "Test123456",
  UserAttributes: [
    {
    Name: "email",
    Value: "user-001@google.com"
    },
    {
    Name: "email_verified",
    Value: "true"
    }
  ]
};

cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser(poolData, (error, data) => {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(data);
});
```

The output of the command is below

```
{
  User: {
    Username: 'e9c137e4-6482-4bf5-9fb9-03f764dd0b4b',
    Attributes: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    UserCreateDate: 2021-04-27T14:17:43.856Z,
    UserLastModifiedDate: 2021-04-27T14:17:43.856Z,
    Enabled: true,
    UserStatus: 'FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD'
  }
}
```

From this output I take the `Username` value and use it next to confirm the user with `adminConfirmSignUp` command:

```
var params = {
  UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID, 
  Username: 'e9c137e4-6482-4bf5-9fb9-03f764dd0b4b', 
  ClientMetadata: {
    'STRING_KEY_1': 'STRING_VALUE_1',
    'STRING_KEY_2': 'STRING_VALUE_2'
  }
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminConfirmSignUp(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
  else     console.log(data);           
});
```

But I am getting the error:

```
NotAuthorizedException: User cannot be confirmed. Current status is FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD
```

Later I found, that I can use `adminSetUserPassword` command that was designed to change the user password. It happens it also confirms the user and it works fine, except it doesn't trigger Post Confirmation lambda which I need to be triggered

```
var params = {
  Password: 'New-password', 
  UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID, 
  Username: 'e9c137e4-6482-4bf5-9fb9-03f764dd0b4b', 
  Permanent: true
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminSetUserPassword(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
  else     console.log(data);           
});
```

How do I confirm the user created with `adminCreateUser` command. I don't want to use the `adminSetUserPassword` to confirm it. I would rather use the `adminConfirmSignUp` command that should confirm the user and trigger the Post Confirmation lambda. Please advise.

Comment: What do you mean by "verified"? Cognito has a verified status on the email and phone number, but I don't believe there is such a status on the user. Setting the "email_verified" UserAttribute to "true" should already be setting the email to verified.

Comment: I didn't mean "verified". But I did mean "confirmed". The email is indeed can be verified. But the user is "confirmed" after the user enters the four digit confirmation number the user receives from Cognito to confirm their identity.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your post-confirmation lambda isn't triggered when they set their new password?

Comment: I double checked it again, The Post Confirmation lambda is not triggered on `adminSetUserPassword` even while the user will be marked as confirmed in Cognito User Pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is known issue.

Found a workaround [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=775800#jive-message-886651)

Might suit your use-case depending on what behavior you expect. Perform a check in a post-authentication handler and do your post confirmation logic there as well as in your post-confirmation handler.

```py
def handler(event, _):
    ''' handle post auth event '''
    status = event['request']['userAttributes']['cognito:user_status']
 
    # If the status hasn't been confirmed yet, we can assume it now is
    if status == 'FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD':
       # Do Something
 
    return event
```

`AdminConfirmSignUp` still won't call the post-confirmation handler so don't waste your time to get it working. If you want to perform some logic as part of a user provisioning step just call the handler yourself, don't count on cognito making sense.